# How to save values with loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to add the returned value from the `test()` function into a variable result, but `+=` does not seem to work. I get the error "invalid variable initialization".
I also tried replacing `i++` to `i+=` which didnt work either. Maybe I'm totally wrong and should use a while loop instead? I'm quite lost..

I want 'result' to look something like this:

```
var result = no no no 0no 0no no;
```

etc (with no whitespace, of course).

Any help much appreciated! Thanks

```
function test(no){

            if (no <= 15){              
                return '0' + parseInt(no);
            }

            else {              
                return parseInt(no); 
            }       
}


        for(i = 0; i < pics.length; i++){

            var b = pics[i].value;

            var result += test(b);

        }
```

Comment: Given the syntax and variable names, I'm assuming JavaScript and have retagged as such. ActionScript (or any other ECMAScript-based language) is another likely choice, but they have identical syntaxes in this example.

Comment: sorry should have taged it as javascript, my bad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every time your loop starts, `var result` goes away. You need to move it outside the loop:

```
var result = ''; // lives outside loop
for(i = 0; i < pics.length; i++)
{
    var b = pics[i].value;
    result += test(b);
}
```

Comment: the result is a string, it should be initialized to '' not 0.

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialize result as a string not as a var.

e.g.

outside the loop

string result = string.Empty;

for loop

result += test(b);

end for loop

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing that error because you are using the increment operator on a newly declared variable.  Use '=':

```
for(i = 0; i < pics.length; i++)
{
   var b = pics[i].value;
   var result = test(b);
}
```

Although, as GMain pointed out, the real solution is to move the 'result' variable declaration outside of the for loop.

Comment: result is a cumulative concatenation of the results of test() on each element.

Comment: No need for the downvote.  I explained the reason for his compile error.

Comment: Although you're right about why the interpreter is complaining, so I'll vote you up to zero.

Comment: oops - lol... I should remember that C# isn't the only language in existence!  Thanks for the upvote...